# obfuscate JS before FireBase Deploy

Tags: firebase-hosting

I have started using Firebase to host an app I am building in js.
I want to be able to obfuscate my java script code before I deploy it to FireBase.

I couldn't find a way of doing this automatically with firebase, so I downloaded the closure compiler, and started writing a deploy.bat batch file that would....

1. Copy all my code and assets from my public folder to a deploy folder
2. Obfuscate the JS
3. Deploy the site to Firebase.

However now I have found out that you cant have separate folders for dev local hosting e.g. (public - using the emulator) and another folder for what should be deployed to firebase.

Could anyone suggest how I can get around this ?

Comment: why bother? can you elaborate why you need to obfuscate your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the folders into a "development" and "production" build. However care should be taken to ensure that your tests pass against your production build as well as the development build.

The following folder structure will allow to deploy your obfuscated code by calling `npm run build` followed by `npm run deploy` from the `project/dev` folder in your terminal.

```
- /project
  - /prod
    - .firebaserc
    - firebase.json
    - /public
      - ... (obfuscated files)
  - /dev
    - .firebaserc
    - firebase.json
    - package.json
    - /public
      - ... (source files)
```

In `project/dev/firebase.json`, merge in this to get `firebase deploy` to deliberately crash if accidentally called from inside of `project/dev`:

```
"hosting": {
  "predeploy": "node -e \"process.exit(1)\""
}
```

In `project/dev/package.json`, merge in this so that your code is built/obfuscated into the `project/prod` directory:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "npm run build-hosting && ...",
  "build-hosting": "INSERT-TOOL-HERE --srcDir ./public --outDir ../prod/public",
  "deploy": "npm run deploy-hosting && ...",
  "deploy-hosting": "pushd ../prod && firebase deploy --only hosting && popd",
}
```